# Office 365 Graph API - inferenceClassification always 'focused' on mails that hit Outlook rules

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

We've noticed some strange behaviour with the **inferenceClassification** property in the Office 365 Graph API, where any email which matches the criteria of an Outlook rule in the user's mailbox is automatically set to '**focused**'.

This can be reproduced very easily, as shown below.

In this example, I have setup an Outlook rule to move all emails received from notifications@github.com to a specified custom folder. Once this rule is in place, all emails matching this rule have an inferenceClassification value of '**focused**'

[image]

Then, after disabling the Outlook rule, the next email received from notifications@github.com has an inferenceClassification value of '**other**'.

[image]

It's worth noting that when turning the rule on/off, the inferenceClassification property doesn't change on emails you've already received. The value will only change for emails received after the rule is flipped on/off.

I can't imagine this is by design, so I'm guessing this is a bug? Generally speaking we have found this property to be very useful and accurate, so it would be great to get this bug fixed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you seeing class Outlook rules showing up in https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/inferenceClassification/overrides as well?

Comment: Hi @MarcLaFleur-MSFT - I get an empty result set for that query